# Access: After Running my VBA code data get split in two records

Tags: vba, ms-access

Ok guys, I'm somewhat new to Access and VBA and I need some help. I've been trying to figure out a problem I'm having my database is suppose to save all the data entered into a form onto a table my when i try to save it splits the record. I have tried everything but can't get it to work.

[image: Form for Data entry]

Just FYI the form auto populates: Name, Phone and Email when ID is entered and Equipment when Tag # is entered.

[image: How table looks like when submit button is pressed]

Here is my VBA Code

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Submit_button_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("student_check_out")

rec.AddNew
rec("ID") = Me.PID
rec("Student Name") = Me.Borrower
rec("Phone") = Me.PHONE
rec("E-mail") = Me.EMAIL
rec("Tag #") = Me.Tag
rec("Equipment") = Me.Equipment
rec("Class") = Me.Class
rec("CDL Staff") = Me.CDL_Staff
rec("Check Out Date") = Me.Check_Out_Date
rec.Update
rec.Close

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Students"

End Sub
```

Comment: Those fields look like they are bound to a table (you can see that by the edit mark in the record selector). What happens when you don't press the submit button, but just enter the info and close the form?

Comment: If this is bound form, there's no need for a submit button, data is saved automatically.

Comment: Data is saved when 1. close table/query/form or 2. move to another record or 3. run code to save. As Kostas K. said, data is automatically saved from a bound form with bound controls. Name parts should be in separate fields: FirstName, LastName, MidName. Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Better would be TagNum or Tag_Num and EMail or E_Mail. Also, no reserved words (such as Date) as names. I would have expected Tag to be a reserved word but it is not in list I looked at.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the form is not bound. "Class" is a reserved word (see it highlighted "blue" in the code). Please rename the textbox, even if it's "Class_" or "Class1", etc.